# I get a TypeError "StringVar object isnt callable"

Tags: python, tkinter

I want it to be able to add the different types with different prices into a simple GUI but I keep getting this callback error
I was copying my code from a simple calculator i made a while back but im not sure what is different, is the stringvar interupting something?

```
from tkinter import *

def price():
    num1 = eval(txtFirst())
    first = num1 * 22.75
    num2 = eval(txtSecond())
    second = num2 * 100
    num3 = eval(txtThird())
    third = num3 * 20.50
    num4 = eval(txtFourth())
    fourth = num4 * 90
    num5 = eval(txtFifth())
    fifth = num5 * 25.50
    num6 = eval(txtSixth())
    sixth = num6 * 125.50
    sum = first + second + third + fourth + fifth + sixth
    cost.set("Sum: " + str(sum))


window = Tk()
window.title("Chicken Feed")
window.geometry("500x500")
Label(window, text="Feed\nType:").grid(row=0, column=0)
Label(window, text="Amount:").grid(row=0,column=1)
Label(window, text="Feed\nCost:").grid(row=0, column=2)
Label(window, text="10kg Pellets:").grid(row=1,column=0)
Label(window, text="50kg Pellets:").grid(row=2,column=0)
Label(window, text="10kg Mash:").grid(row=3,column=0)
Label(window, text="50kg Mash:").grid(row=4,column=0)
Label(window, text="10kg Enhanced:").grid(row=5,column=0)
Label(window, text="50kg Pellets:").grid(row=6,column=0)


cost = StringVar()
cost = Entry(window, state='readonly', width=20, textvariable=cost)
cost.grid(row=1, column=2, columnspan=3, padx=20, pady=6)


txtFirst = StringVar()
entFirst = Entry(window, width=5, textvariable=txtFirst)
entFirst.grid(row=1, column=1)

txtSecond = StringVar()
entSecond = Entry(window, width=5, textvariable=txtSecond)
entSecond.grid(row=2, column=1)

txtThird = StringVar()
entThird = Entry(window, width=5, textvariable=txtThird)
entThird.grid(row=3, column=1)

txtFourth = StringVar()
entFourth = Entry(window, width=5, textvariable=txtFourth)
entFourth.grid(row=4, column=1)

txtFifth = StringVar()
entFifth = Entry(window, width=5, textvariable=txtFifth)
entFifth.grid(row=5, column=1)

txtSixth = StringVar()
entSixth = Entry(window, width=5, textvariable=txtSixth)
entSixth.grid(row=6, column=1)

btnAdd = Button(window, text="Calculate", width=3, command=price)
btnAdd.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=20)

window.mainloop()
```

I keep getting the error after I enter a number into my entry widget:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Luke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Luke\Desktop\stage2.py", line 4, in price
    num1 = eval(txtFirst())
TypeError: 'StringVar' object is not callable
```

Comment: Remove parenthesis there `num1 = eval(txtFirst)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you want to do is return the value of `txtFirst`. Don't use `eval()` for this. To get the value:

```
num1 = txtFirst.get()
```

Comment: It then say: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' i have no idea what that even means

Comment: That new error is not on that line, it is later. You have fixed one error, but there is another. Look closely at the traceback of the new error and you can see it is somewhere else: probably here: `first = num1 * 22.75`. You are trying to multiply a string by a float.

Comment: its given to the first = num1 * 22.75 do i have to change num or first or something to an integer or a float or something

Comment: Yes. If you want to do arithmetic with it I would expect you create `num1` as one of `DoubleVar`, `IntVar`. Or else, of course, convert the value.

Comment: how do i edit the num1? do i do it before the `def` ie `num1 = DoubleVar`?

Comment: When you do this: `txtFirst = StringVar()` you create an object that can hold a string. But if you want to do arithmetic with the value you get, then you either convert it to a number (`first = float(num1) * 22.75`) or else create an object that can hold a number instead (`txtFirst = DoubleVar()`). SO's goal is to present a question and an answer that may be useful to future visitors. Turning the comments section into an interactive ongoing debugging session doesn't further that goal. If you have yet another question then ask a fresh one.